# Largest possible order in the multiplicative group mod n

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

> I am trying to figure out what is the largest possible order that an element of the multiplicative group $\bmod{n}$ can have if $n=p_1^{k_1} \cdot p_2^{k_2} \cdot \dots \cdot p_m^{k_m}$.

then I can prove that

$$U(n) \cong U(p_1^{k_1}) \times U(p_2^{k_2}) \times \dots \times U(p_m^{k_m})$$

Now I know from my number theory book, that if $p_i$ is an odd prime, then $p_i^{k_i}$ has a primitive root, which makes $U(p_i^{k_i})$ cyclic. So the largest order of an element in that group is $\phi(p_i^{k_i})$.
I also know, that $2$ and $4$ have primitive roots, so the largest orders in $U(2)$ and $U(2^2)$ are $\phi(2)$ and $\phi(2^2)$ respectively.

However, I am having trouble with $U(2^k)$ where $k\geq 3$.

I was able to show that for any $x\in U(2^k), \quad x^{2^{k-2}}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}$.

But how can I show that there $\textbf{must}$ be an element of order $2^{k-2}$ in $U(2^k), k\geq3$ ?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/generators-of-the-multiplicative-group-modulo-2k).

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, that was certainly helpful. However, how is enough to show that $5^{2^{k-3}}\not\equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}$? Don't we have to consider all the other possible exponents, $5^{2^{k-i}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $5$ has order $2^{k-2}$ in $U(2^k)$ for $k\ge3$. To prove this
use induction to prove that
$$5^{2^r}\equiv 1+2^{r+2}\pmod{2^{r+3}}$$
for all integers $r\ge0$.

Comment: I proved what you suggested, but I am still having troubles using that result to conclude that $5$ has order $2^{k-2}$. How does that follow?

Comment: It shows $5^{2^r}\not\equiv1$ but $5^{2^{r+1}}\equiv1\pmod{2^{r+3}}$.

Comment: Then I know that $5^{2^{k-3}} \not \equiv 1\pmod{2^k}$. How do we know that no smaller exponent of $5$ could be congruent to $1 \pmod{2^k}$?

Comment: You also know $5^{2^{k-2}}\equiv1\pmod{2^k}$. So the order of $5$ is a factor of $2^{k-2}$.

Comment: So the order of $5$ is of form $2^{k-l}, l\geq 2$. We know $l\neq 3$. How do we know that $l\neq 4, 5, ...$ ? Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Could we really have $5^{2^{k-3}}\not\equiv1$ but $5^{2^{k-4}}\equiv1$?

Comment: That last comment made it click, I can finally work it out. Thank you so much!